# Android - float parameters in drawBitmap

Tags: android, image, bitmap, floating-point, drawbitmap

I used this function in my Android program:

public void drawBitmap (Bitmap bitmap, float left, float top, Paint paint)

However, I want to draw my bitmap not in the position 0 x 0, but in the position 10 x 10 **(in PIXELS)**. The drawBitmap function, however, only accepts float numbers...

How can I achieve this??

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `drawBitmap(bitmap, 10.f, 10.f, ... )`... Considering the transformation matrix of the canvas is set to the identity matrix, that is

Comment: Oh, god. I can`t believe I haven`t tried that... It worked! Thanks K-ballo! Just one more question. Why is it that those parameters use float then? I just didn`t get it.

Comment: The documentation is just so poor in my opinion... It just says that the parameters are float number, but it doesn`t give one single example or explains what those float numbers really are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `drawBitmap(bitmap, 10.f, 10.f, ... )`? Considering the transformation matrix of the canvas is set to the identity matrix, that is.

The reason those parameters are `float` is probably that the `Canvas` does not operate in an integer space (pixels), but in a user specified space defined by a transformation matrix. If you where to set a custom transformation matrix to scale by `2` then using `0.5, 0.5` would end up mapping to pixel `1, 1`. This means you could also set a custom transformation to translate by `10, 10` and then just simply draw the bitmap without specifying a destination.